# Change location and appearance of Section Changer tab indicator on Galaxy Gear?

Tags: tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, samsung-galaxy-gear

I am having trouble with the Section Changer widget on the Galaxy Gear.

I have added a Section Changer to my web app to give it multiple pages. I would like the page/tab indicator to display as something similar to the following (Notice the thin page indicator at the bottom of the screen, above the Back button):

[image]

The Section Changer widget automatically generates the page indicator after the content loads. I am able to move it in the Chrome element inspector after it is created, but the Section Changer widget dynamically adds the tab indicator at runtime, so I have no opportunity to change where it appears.

The Samsung documentation is severely lacking. I found a few links online ([like this one](http://developer.samsung.com/forum/board/thread/view.do?boardName=SDK&messageId=265719)) with people using a `scrollbar:` option when creating the Section Changer, but the `scrollbar` option doesn't seem to be listed anywhere in the documentation???

Here is the code I am using to create my Section Changer:

```
var page = document.getElementById("main"),
    changer = document.getElementById("maincontent"),
    sectionChanger;

page.addEventListener("pagebeforeshow", function() {
    // Create SectionChanger object
    sectionChanger = new tau.widget.SectionChanger(changer, {
        circular: true,
        orientation: "horizontal",
        useBouncingEffect: false,
        scrollbar: "tab"
    });
});
```

This code is almost exactly like the example in the documentation.

And here is a screenshot of my app with the Section Changer indicator at the top (running in emulator, but it looks identical on the actual watch):

[image]

Notice the tab indicator at the top under the heading. Any way I can move it to the bottom, below the rest of the content?